# UFW firewall start up on ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: ufw

On all 3 of my Ubuntu 14.04.3 workstations when restarted the UFW firewall is deactivated and has to be started manually `sudo ufw enable`. My UFW.conf is set to enable startup as follows:

> # Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
>   # to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
>   ENABLED=yes

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago, but here is a solution.
(Duplicate of [14.04 missing “/etc/init.d/ufw”? my firewall never auto starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474216/14-04-missing-etc-init-d-ufw-my-firewall-never-auto-starts/742368#742368))

For the effort that went into figuring out the solution, the answer is surprisingly simple.

In /etc/init/ufw.conf:

1) Comment out lines 9 - 11
2) Insert after line 11: start on startup

Fixes the whole problem, including logging to /var/log/ufw.log.

**Note**
If you have `iptables-persistent` installed, you must disable it.
Move `iptables-persistent` out of /etc/init.d and rename all the symlinks in `rc0.d`-`rcS.d` by making the 1st letter (S or K) lower case.  (Or move them out.)